# Rust - downloading files via handmade tcp/http server

Tags: file, http, rust, tcp, download

I'm trying to implement simple tcp/http server on Rust. Main feature is possibility to download files from server via url. As exapmple: localhost:port/root_storage/someFile.fileExt

Main function:

```
fn main() {
    let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7000").unwrap();
    println!("Server starded!");
    for stream in tcp_listener.incoming()
    {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();
        handle_connection(stream);
    }
}
```

I'm receiving request with tcpStream, parsing to get incoming url etc.
Then I'm tryiting to send some file back to browser and download him on client side.

```
 if  http_request[0].contains("storage/10mb.pdf")  {
    status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

    let buf_content = fs::read("storage/10mb.pdf").unwrap();
    let contents = unsafe {String::from_utf8_unchecked(buf_content)};
    length = contents.len();

    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.pdf\"\r\n
    Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n
    {contents}");
}
```

It works, but only with pdf format.

This code won't occure file downloading, just showing content of file in browser:

```
    else if http_request[0].contains("storage/10mb.txt")  {
    status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

    let buf_content = fs::read("storage/10mb.txt").unwrap();
    let contents =  unsafe {String::from_utf8_unchecked(buf_content)};
    length = contents.len();

    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.txt\"\r\n
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n
    {contents}");

stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
stream.flush().unwrap();
```

My assumption it's about in contents encoding.
I don't know why - Content-Disposition and other headers doesn't work at all. If I remove Content-Disposition from pdf case. It will download file anyway.

What's wrong with my implementation? May be I encode contents in wrong way or something else?

**UPD:**
Have this, but also no effect

```
if  http_request[0].contains("storage/10mb.pdf")  {
    status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

    let buf_content = fs::read("storage/10mb.pdf").unwrap();
    length = buf_content.len();

    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.pdf\"\r\n
    Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n");
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.write_all(&buf_content).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
else if http_request[0].contains("storage/10mb.txt")  {
    status_line = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK";

    let buf_content = fs::read("storage/10mb.txt").unwrap();
    length = buf_content.len();

    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.txt\"\r\n
    Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n");
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.write_all(&buf_content).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: If it's just the matter of how the browser displays the content, then `Content-Type: text/plain` could help... As far as I understand, this could be related to some settings in the browser.

Comment: Not directly related but, does your server manage `Connection: keep-alive`? If not and you unconditionally close the connection after the http reply, then you should add `Connection: close` in the reply header.

Comment: I tried, no result(

Comment: @prog-fh not sure about keep-alive, but request sends with Connection: keep-alive. How can I check does  server support keep-alive and should i close him every time?

Comment: You actually wrote the server, you probably know if it handles keep-alive or not. If you are not certain, then this certainly not the case.

Comment: Nitpick: `String::from_utf8_unchecked()` for PDF file looks wrong.

Comment: If your browser obtains the content of the text file but does not display/save it as you expect, then you should have a look at your browser settings, in the section related to Applications/Mime-types.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman without `from_utf8_unchecked` it doesn't work and throw exception about "invalid utf8"

Comment: @Dkwcs Because it is invalid UTF-8. You should not use `String`. Using `_unchecked()` fixes nothing, just makes it worse.

Comment: The content (not the header) of an HTTP reply, should not be converted to text. Send the reply header as text, then the content as raw bytes.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what should I use to send pdf?
   `let buf_content = fs::read("storage/10mb.pdf").unwrap();
    length = buf_content.len();
    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.pdf\"\r\n
    Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n");
    stream.write_all(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.write_all(&buf_content).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();` ?

Comment: for pdf or whatever --> raw-bytes. If these bytes initially described text, then the receiver will interpret them as text, if these bytes initially described something else (pdf, image...) then the receiver will interpret them accordingly (`Content-Type` helps).

Comment: @prog-fh I've updated post. Check pls

Comment: Ok, then what about your browser? does it receive everything? does it display/save as you expect?

Comment: @prog-fh he works as earlier
For pdf - downloading, for txt - only showing in the browser tab, for image - downloading, but image is corrupted.

Comment: Did you check the browser settings related to Applications/Mime-Types?

Comment: @prog-fh cant' find this settings in google chrome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the multiline text literal.

Every line contains an implicit `\n` after your explicit `\r\n` and the next line starts with many spaces before the option name.

When the browser receives this reply header, it does not understand it and probably tries to display everything...

If you end the lines with `\` (and nothing behind, not even a space), then only your explicit `\r\n` will end the lines and the leading spaces will be discarded.

```rust
    response = format!("{status_line}\r\n\
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"10mb.txt\"\r\n\
    Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\
    Content-Length: {length}\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Wow, It WORKS. Greate man. Don't know about implicit `\n`. But strange how it worked with PDF files?

Comment: Could you recommend the best way of sending response? I mean doing like current code or may be create 1 buffer and write to him `resposnse.as_bytes()` and then buf_content or any diffrent way?

Comment: @Dkwcs In my opinion, what you are doing here is correct: send the bytes which constitute the textual http-reply header (with `.as_bytes()`), then send the actual content as bytes without any transformation. About the pdf file that seemed to be working in the incorrect conditions, I think it's just some kind of chance. pdf contains a combination of text et binary elements. Maybe the browser/pdf-reader is smart enough to ignore the unexpected textual parts?